# Reading qr code with Zxing .Net is not working when taking photo with camera in WinJS

Tags: uwp, qr-code, winjs, zxing.net

[image] - I installed Zxing. Net  library for scanning a QR code in winJS.When 
   I take a  QR code image from file picker it working fine but when I
   capture image of QR code from piece of paper or from any charger
   device and try, it gives "No Barcode Found" result .I could not
   understand why this happening. Is there any problem when image
   capture from Camera.The same code worked well when I was using the
   file picker API. Let me know where I went wrong.Any help would be
   appreciated

```
    following javascript code :

(
function () {
    "use strict";

    WinJS.Binding.optimizeBindingReferences = true;

    var app = WinJS.Application;
    var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;

    app.onactivated = function (args) {
        if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
            if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
                // TODO: This application has been newly launched. Initialize
                // your application here.

                var dialog = new Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI();
                var aspectRatio = { width: 1, height: 1 };
                dialog.photoSettings.croppedAspectRatio = aspectRatio;
                dialog.captureFileAsync(Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUIMode.photo).then(function (file) {

                    if (file) {
                        // draw the image
                        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasDecode')
                        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                        var img = new Image;
                        img.onload = function () {
                            canvas.width = img.width;
                            canvas.height = img.height;
                            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
                        }
                        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                        // open a stream from the image
                        return file.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.readWrite);
                    }
                })
                .then(function (stream) {
                    if (stream) {
                        // create a decoder from the image stream
                        return Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.createAsync(stream);
                    }
                })
                .done(function (decoder) {
                    if (decoder) {
                        // get the raw pixel data from the decoder
                        decoder.getPixelDataAsync().then(function (pixelDataProvider) {
                            var rawPixels = pixelDataProvider.detachPixelData();
                            var pixels, format; // Assign these in the below switch block.

                            switch (decoder.bitmapPixelFormat) {
                                case Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapPixelFormat.rgba16:
                                    // Allocate a typed array with the raw pixel data
                                    var pixelBufferView_U8 = new Uint8Array(rawPixels);

                                    // Uint16Array provides a typed view into the raw 8 bit pixel data.
                                    pixels = new Uint16Array(pixelBufferView_U8.buffer);
                                    if (decoder.bitmapAlphaMode == Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapAlphaMode.straight)
                                        format = ZXing.BitmapFormat.rgba32;
                                    else
                                        format = ZXing.BitmapFormat.rgb32;
                                    break;

                                case Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapPixelFormat.rgba8:
                                    // For 8 bit pixel formats, just use the returned pixel array.
                                    pixels = rawPixels;
                                    if (decoder.bitmapAlphaMode == Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapAlphaMode.straight)
                                        format = ZXing.BitmapFormat.rgba32;
                                    else
                                        format = ZXing.BitmapFormat.rgb32;
                                    break;

                                case Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapPixelFormat.bgra8:
                                    // For 8 bit pixel formats, just use the returned pixel array.
                                    pixels = rawPixels;
                                    if (decoder.bitmapAlphaMode == Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapAlphaMode.straight)
                                        format = ZXing.BitmapFormat.bgra32;
                                    else
                                        format = ZXing.BitmapFormat.bgr32;
                                    break;
                            }
                            // create a barcode reader
                            var reader = new ZXing.BarcodeReader();
                            reader.onresultpointfound = function (resultPoint) {
                                // do something with the resultpoint location
                            }
                            // try to decode the raw pixel data
                            var result = reader.decode(pixels, decoder.pixelWidth, decoder.pixelHeight, format);
                            // show the result
                            if (result) {
                                document.getElementById("result").innerText = result.text;
                            }
                            else {
                                document.getElementById("result").innerText = "no barcode found";
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            } else {
                // TODO: This application has been reactivated from suspension.
                // Restore application state here.
            }
            args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());
        }
    };

    app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {

    };

    app.start();
    })();
```

[image]

Comment: The margin of the QR code is a factor in recognizing, the smaller the better. Try to take the photo and make the QR code take up as much space as possible (without losing focus).

Comment: i have attached images of Qr code .there is focus on Qr code but it still shows "No Barcode Found"

Comment: "When I take a QR code image from file picker it working fine", for this, where is this image come from? Is it taken by the same device camera?

Comment: yes..it takes by the same device camera

Comment: the image is distorted. you can try pointing the camera right at the image (without an angle).